# Sonarqube 5.2 / Checkstyle plugin 2.3 : Enabling SummaryJavadocCheck makes the analysis failed

Tags: java, sonarqube

I recently change my SONARQUBE configuration:

Before:

- SonarQube 5.1
- Java plugin 3.0
- PMD plugin 2.3
- Checkstyle plugin 2.2
- FindBugs plugin 3.2
- Issue Assign plugin 1.6

After:

- SonarQube 5.1
- Java plugin 3.3
- PMD plugin 2.4.1
- Checkstyle plugin 2.3
- FindBugs plugin 3.2
- Issue Assign plugin 1.6

On new configuration I have enabled all new rules brought from 3.1 to 3.2 Java plugin version.

The analysis batch fails at IssueTracking Decorating stage of the batch analysis:

```
[INFO] [08:37:25.503] Compare over 1 days (2015-05-31, analysis of Fri May 29 21:49:21 BST 2015)
[INFO] [08:37:25.504] Compare over 7 days (2015-05-25, analysis of Mon May 25 08:07:18 BST 2015)
[INFO] [08:37:25.505] Compare over 30 days (2015-05-02, analysis of Sat May 02 00:19:16 BST 2015)
[INFO] [08:37:25.506] Compare to date 2014-04-01 (analysis of 2014-06-06)
[INFO] [08:37:25.741] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [08:37:25.744] Issue 2c785d7e-3a5b-4282-9c5b-39bd4d645a81 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: NOT_NEW
[INFO] [08:37:25.744] Issue ebcf237e-1bc5-407c-9d84-1224f029b7f6 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.748] Issue 01da957a-a184-4baa-8adf-15984869b1fc won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.749] Issue 4fe8ef3e-de23-4c59-8846-21b4cd5a875b won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.749] Issue 6684e397-09ce-488f-8a10-4e5c1eb40492 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.749] Issue 6abbb736-898d-4592-bc05-4a52062c57c8 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.749] Issue 7375deed-09a7-45b1-8184-40f0b4a4666f won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.749] Issue 90d82183-edf0-4854-b096-e9a9105af3ad won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.750] Issue 9170b68c-909b-40c7-aea1-571d8e99ac74 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
[INFO] [08:37:25.750] Issue 95221ab3-aa9f-4dc3-9a03-11ddb7dea082 won't be auto-assigned.  Reason: BEFORE_CUTOFF_DATE
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project myapp: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@7d30e345[key=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,path=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,filename=EquityAccountingHandler.java,language=Java]': 489 -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project myapp: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@7d30e345[key=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,path=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,filename=EquityAccountingHandler.java,language=Java]'
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@7d30e345[key=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,path=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,filename=EquityAccountingHandler.java,language=Java]'
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@7d30e345[key=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,path=src/main/java/com/mycompany/EquityAccountingHandler.java,filename=EquityAccountingHandler.java,language=Java]'
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:104)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:87)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:71)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 489
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.FileHashes.getHash(FileHashes.java:89)
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.setChecksumOnNewIssues(IssueTracking.java:66)
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:139)
        at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:113)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:96)
        ... 57 more
```

Any idea what happened?

**EDIT:**

I removed new rule *checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.javadoc.SummaryJavadocCheck* brought by checkstyle 2.3 plugin version. The analysis works correctly now.

Comment: Hi Laurent, is that possible that you've got the same issue as http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-while-decorating-Java-file-td5034646.html ?

Comment: Hi Fabrice. Thanks for the link. It was helpful. I removed new rule SummaryJavadocCheck brought by checkstyle 2.3 plugin version. The analysis works correctly now.

Comment: OK, thanks for the information. I will put this as an answer so that other users can benefit from this. If you can validate it, it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to some Checkstyle rules. If you remove them, this solves the problem.

For further reference: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-while-decorating-Java-file-td5034646.html

Comment: Hi any SonarSource JIRA ticket for that issue?