# How to find the rule throwing an ArrayOutOfBoundsException after activating a bunch of rules in Sonarqube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I recently activated following rules in Sonarqube (5.1.1):

- squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod ("@Deprecated" code should not be used)
- squid:S2737 ("catch" clauses should do more than rethrow)
- squid:S3398 ("private" methods called only by inner classes should be moved to those classes)
- squid:LeftCurlyBraceEndLineCheck (An open curly brace should be located at the end of a line)
- squid:S2445 (Blocks synchronized on fields should not contain assignments of new objects to those fields)
- pmd:BooleanGetMethodName (Boolean Get Method Name)
- squid:S1940 (Boolean checks should not be inverted)
- pmd:CallSuperInConstructor (Call Super In Constructor)
- squid:S2147 (Catches should be combined)
- findbugs:NM_LCASE_TOSTRING (Class defines tostring(); should it be toString()?)
- squid:RightCurlyBraceDifferentLineAsNextBlockCheck (Close curly brace and the next "else", "catch" and "finally" keywords should be on two different lines)
- squid:S1451 (Copyright and license headers should be defined)
- fb-contrib:AOM_ABSTRACT_OVERRIDDEN_METHOD (Correctness - Abstract method overrides a concrete implementation)
- fb-contrib:SPP_STUTTERED_ASSIGNMENT (Correctness - Method assigns a value to a local twice in a row)
- fb-contrib:SPP_TOSTRING_ON_STRING (Correctness - Method calls toString() on a String)
- fb-contrib:CCNE_COMPARE_CLASS_EQUALS_NAME (Correctness - Method compares class name instead of comparing class)
- fb-contrib:SLS_SUSPICIOUS_LOOP_SEARCH (Correctness - Method continues with a loop without break after finding an setting a variable)
- fb-contrib:LSYC_LOCAL_SYNCHRONIZED_COLLECTION (Correctness - Method creates local variable-based synchronized collection)
- fb-contrib:OC_OVERZEALOUS_CASTING (Correctness - Method manually casts the right hand side of an assignment more specifically than needed)
- fb-contrib:LO_INCORRECT_NUMBER_OF_ANCHOR_PARAMETERS (Correctness - Method passes an incorrect number of parameters to an SLF4J logging statement)
- fb-contrib:SPP_USE_MATH_CONSTANT (Correctness - Method uses non standard math constant)
- findbugs:RV_01_TO_INT (Correctness - Random value from 0 to 1 is coerced to the integer 0)
- findbugs:EQ_ALWAYS_FALSE (Correctness - equals method always returns false)
- findbugs:EQ_ALWAYS_TRUE (Correctness - equals method always returns true)
- findbugs:SKIPPED_CLASS_TOO_BIG (Dodgy - Class too big for analysis)
- FIXTEST (template squid:S124: Comments matching a regular expression should be handled )
- common-java:FailedUnitTests (Failed unit tests should be fixed)
- pmd:GodClass (God Class)
- findbugs:IIO_INEFFICIENT_INDEX_OF (Inefficient use of String.indexOf(String))
- findbugs:IIO_INEFFICIENT_LAST_INDEX_OF (Inefficient use of String.lastIndexOf(String))
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnitTestContainsTooManyAsserts (JUnit Test Contains Too Many Asserts)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnitUseExpected (JUnit Use Expected)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnitSpelling (JUnit spelling)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnitStaticSuite (JUnit static suite)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnitTestsShouldIncludeAssert (JUnit tests should include an assert)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnit4SuitesShouldUseSuiteAnnotation (JUnit4 Suites Should Use Suite Annotation)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnit4TestShouldUseAfterAnnotation (JUnit4 Test Should Use After Annotation)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnit4TestShouldUseBeforeAnnotation (JUnit4 Test Should Use Before Annotation)
- pmd-unit-tests:JUnit4TestShouldUseTestAnnotation (JUnit4 Test Should Use Test Annotation)
- squid:S2701 (Literal boolean values should not be used in assertions)
- pmd:LocalVariableCouldBeFinal (Local variable could be final)
- squid:S1845 (Methods and field names should not be the same or differ only by capitalization)
- squid:S1659 (Multiple variables should not be declared on the same line)
- findbugs:IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC (Multithreaded correctness - Inconsistent synchronization)
- fb-contrib:UEC_USE_ENUM_COLLECTIONS (Performance - Class uses an ordinary set or map with an enum class as the key)
- findbugs:HSC_HUGE_SHARED_STRING_CONSTANT (Performance - Huge string constants is duplicated across multiple class files)
- findbugs:DM_BOOLEAN_CTOR (Performance - Method invokes inefficient Boolean constructor; use Boolean.valueOf(...) instead)
- findbugs:DM_FP_NUMBER_CTOR (Performance - Method invokes inefficient floating-point Number constructor; use static valueOf instead)
- findbugs:DM_STRING_VOID_CTOR (Performance - Method invokes inefficient new String() constructor)
- findbugs:DM_STRING_CTOR (Performance - Method invokes inefficient new String(String) constructor
- fb-contrib:NAB_NEEDLESS_BOOLEAN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION (Performance - Method needlessly boxes a boolean constant)
- fb-contrib:BSB_BLOATED_SYNCHRONIZED_BLOCK (Performance - Method overly synchronizes a block of code)
- fb-contrib:LO_APPENDED_STRING_IN_FORMAT_STRING (Performance - Method passes a concatenated string to Slf4j's format string)
- fb-contrib:UCPM_USE_CHARACTER_PARAMETERIZED_METHOD (Performance - Method passes constant String of length 1 to character overridden method)
- fb-contrib:SG_SLUGGISH_GUI (Performance - Method performs time consuming operation in GUI thread)
- fb-contrib:DSOC_DUBIOUS_SET_OF_COLLECTIONS (Performance - Method uses a set of collections)
- fb-contrib:SPP_USELESS_TERNARY (Performance - Method uses a ternary operator to cast a boolean to true or false)
- fb-contrib:SPP_USE_GET0 (Performance - Method uses iterator().next() on a List to get the first item)
- fb-contrib:DDC_DOUBLE_DATE_COMPARISON (Performance - Method uses two date comparisons when one would do)
- findbugs:DM_NEXTINT_VIA_NEXTDOUBLE (Performance - Use the nextInt method of Random rather than nextDouble to generate a random integer)
- pmd:RedundantFieldInitializer (Redundant Field Initializer)
- squid:S2333 (Redundant modifiers should not be used)
- findsecbugs:REDOS (Security - Regex DOS (ReDOS))
- squid:S1697 (Short-circuit logic should be used to prevent null pointer dereferences in conditionals)
- pmd:SimplifyStartsWith (Simplify Starts With)
- pmd-unit-tests:SimplifyBooleanAssertion (Simplify boolean assertion)
- fb-contrib:SPP_SERIALVER_SHOULD_BE_PRIVATE (Style - Class defines a serialVersionUID as non private)
- fb-contrib:NOS_NON_OWNED_SYNCHRONIZATION (Style - Class uses non owned variables to synchronize on)
- fb-contrib:COM_COPIED_OVERRIDDEN_METHOD (Style - Method is implemented with an exact copy of its superclass's method)
- fb-contrib:SPP_EMPTY_CASING (Style - Method passes an empty string to equalsIgnoreCase or compareToIgnoreCase)
- fb-contrib:CFS_CONFUSING_FUNCTION_SEMANTICS (Style - Method returns modified parameter)
- fb-contrib:STB_STACKED_TRY_BLOCKS (Style - Method stacks similar try/catch blocks)
- fb-contrib:USBR_UNNECESSARY_STORE_BEFORE_RETURN (Style - Method stores return result in local before immediately returning it)
- fb-contrib:LO_STUTTERED_MESSAGE (Style - Method stutters exception message in logger)
- fb-contrib:MRC_METHOD_RETURNS_CONSTANT (Style - Private method only returns one constant value)
- fb-contrib:UP_UNUSED_PARAMETER (Style - Static or private method has unused parameters)
- squid:S2699 (Tests should include assertions)
- pmd:UnnecessaryFinalModifier (Unnecessary Final Modifier)
- pmd:UnnecessaryFullyQualifiedName (Unnecessary Fully Qualified Name)
- pmd-unit-tests:UnnecessaryBooleanAssertion (Unnecessary boolean assertion)
- pmd:UseArraysAsList (Use Arrays As List)
- pmd:UseConcurrentHashMap (Use ConcurrentHashMap)
- pmd:UseIndexOfChar (Use Index Of Char)
- pmd:UseStringBufferForStringAppends (Use String Buffer For String Appends)
- pmd:UseStringBufferLength (Use String Buffer Length)
- pmd:UseVarargs (Use Varargs)
- squid:S2208 (Wildcard imports should not be used)

Now I get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException:

```
[DEBUG] [16:25:04.971] Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> QProfileEventsDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.design.ProjectDsmDecorator@f11bc3 -> org.sonar.batch.design.SubProjectDsmDecorator@155b434 -> org.sonar.batch.design.DirectoryDsmDecorator@1a9fa00 -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@81db67 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@567bc5 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@1d7c3b5 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@6da7af -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@71df98 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@e7d9d -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@15908eb -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@588740 -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> org.sonar.batch.language.LanguageDistributionDecorator@16cc1dd -> DirectoryTangleIndexDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@1aaebaf -> CommentDensityDecorator -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@deec30 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@1648255 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@1a8bbfd -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@cdf676 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@1efcdcd -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@b06757 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@150bda1 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@1d1b166 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@1d5aaba -> Common Rules for java -> org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator@94dc01 -> org.sonar.batch.debt.DebtDecorator@12bcb44 -> org.sonar.batch.debt.NewDebtDecorator@2df694 -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> org.sonar.batch.debt.SqaleRatingDecorator@1978848 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@18aadb2 -> VariationDecorator -> QualityGateVerifier -> org.sonar.batch.qualitygate.GenerateQualityGateEvents@177f07
[DEBUG] [16:25:05.049] Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@11a5ab8[id=955,key=xxxxxxxxx:XXXXXXXXXXX,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-xxxxxxxxx:XXXXXXXXXXX
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] XXXXXXXXXXX ....................................... FAILURE [06:55 min]
[INFO] XXXXXXXXX ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] XXXXXXXXX ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] XXXXXXXX .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] XXXXXXXXXXXXX ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:56 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-05-12T16:25:05+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 52M/247M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXXXXXX: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@18260be[key=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,path=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/BaseEntity.java,filename=BaseEntity.java,language=Java]': 163 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project XXXXXXXXXXX: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@18260be[key=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,path=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,filename=BaseEntity.java,language=Java]'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@18260be[key=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,path=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,filename=BaseEntity.java,language=Java]'
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to decorate 'org.sonar.api.resources.File@18260be[key=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,path=src/main/java/xxxxxxxxx/model/BaseEntity.java,filename=BaseEntity.java,language=Java]'
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:104)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.decorateResource(DecoratorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.execute(DecoratorsExecutor.java:71)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 163
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.FileHashes.getHash(FileHashes.java:89)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.setChecksumOnNewIssues(IssueTracking.java:66)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTracking.track(IssueTracking.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.doDecorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:139)
    at org.sonar.batch.issue.tracking.IssueTrackingDecorator.decorate(IssueTrackingDecorator.java:113)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DecoratorsExecutor.executeDecorator(DecoratorsExecutor.java:96)
    ... 57 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Build step 'Maven Goals aufrufen' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anybody got an idea how I find the rule causing the problem without manually try every rule on its own?

**Edit:**
I identified the rules causing my problem (I don't know why or if this is project-specific):

- fb-contrib:UCPM_USE_CHARACTER_PARAMETERIZED_METHOD (Performance - Method passes constant String of length 1 to character overridden method)
- fb-contrib:COM_COPIED_OVERRIDDEN_METHOD (Style - Method is implemented with an exact copy of its superclass's method)

Comment: Once I encountered such issue while using pmd rules. Migrated many of them to sonar got solved. Usually when excessive issues are encountered you'd get message like "too manu issues keeping only 1000". Looks like  one or more rule wasn't written well

Comment: Name of the rule won't really help here, can you please share the key of the rule (with its repository name : does the rule comes from findbugs or pmd or checkstyle or SQ analyzer ?).

The best way to investigate this would be to work by dichotomie : activate half of the rule, redo the analysis : if it fails, deactivate again one half, otherwise, redo do the analysis with the other half and iterate until you've pinpoint the problematic rule.

Comment: And you may want to have a look other there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569667/sonarqube-5-2-checkstyle-plugin-2-3-enabling-summaryjavadoccheck-makes-the-a

Comment: @benzonico thank you for your suggestion. I just hoped there is an easier way. I saw the post, sadly I didn't activate any checkstyle rules, so it didn't help me. I will add the ids / keys.